# Optimizar query con subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo esta query simplificada donde tengo un select anidado para sacar la última fecha del material

```
SELECT 
    M.SAP_MATERIAL
    CP.CODIGO AS CODIGO_PUENTE,
     (
      SELECT TOP 1 FECHA_ENVIO FROM 
        CABECERA_ENTRADA AS CAB
        LEFT JOIN DETALLE_ENTRADA AS DET ON  
                                    DET.NUMERO_GUIA = CAB.NUMERO_GUIA 
                                    AND DET.TIPO_GUIA = CAB.TIPO_GUIA 
                                    AND DET.ID_BODEGA = CAB.ID_BODEGA 
                                    AND DET.BOD_SALIDA = CAB.BOD_SALIDA
        WHERE M.SAP_MATERIAL = DET.SAP_MATERIAL
        ORDER BY FECHA_ENVIO DESC                             
   ) AS FECHA
FROM
    MATERIAL AS M
```

Mi pregunta es si esto se puede optimizar para que sea más eficiente, quizás en un left join

Comment: Primero deberías compartir el esquema de las tablas para poder sugerirte la promoción a clave de algún campo. Además, necesitamos conocer el SGBD que estás usando (Postgresql, MySQL, Oracle, SQL Server, etc). Edito: el `SELECT TOP 1` es único de SQL Server, he agregado la etiqueta adecuada.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Poder sugerirte una optimización si conocer la estructura de las tablas y sus índices es casi imposible, pero el patrón de subconsulta a nivel de columna suele ser bastante ineficiente, llevar esta subconsulta a nivel de un `left join` podría mejorar bastante, pero eso dependerá de como tengas configurados los índices. En tu consulta, entiendo, que deseas obtener la `FECHA_ENVIO` más actual por cada `SAP_MATERIAL`, esto, podemos resolverlo básicamente así:

```
SELECT  DET.SAP_MATERIAL, 
        MAX(FECHA_ENVIO) FECHA_ENVIO
    FROM CABECERA_ENTRADA AS CAB
    LEFT JOIN DETALLE_ENTRADA AS DET ON  
        DET.NUMERO_GUIA = CAB.NUMERO_GUIA 
        AND DET.TIPO_GUIA = CAB.TIPO_GUIA 
        AND DET.ID_BODEGA = CAB.ID_BODEGA 
        AND DET.BOD_SALIDA = CAB.BOD_SALIDA
    GROUP  BY DET.SAP_MATERIAL
```

El éxito de la optimización dependerá de esta consulta, la cual podremos incorporar como subconsulta, para lograr lo que buscas:

```
SELECT  M.SAP_MATERIAL,
        CP.CODIGO AS CODIGO_PUENTE,
        F.FECHA_ENVIO AS FECHA
    FROM MATERIAL AS M 
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT  DET.SAP_MATERIAL, 
                       MAX(FECHA_ENVIO) FECHA_ENVIO
                       FROM CABECERA_ENTRADA AS CAB
                       LEFT JOIN DETALLE_ENTRADA AS DET 
                           ON DET.NUMERO_GUIA = CAB.NUMERO_GUIA 
                           AND DET.TIPO_GUIA = CAB.TIPO_GUIA 
                           AND DET.ID_BODEGA = CAB.ID_BODEGA 
                           AND DET.BOD_SALIDA = CAB.BOD_SALIDA
                       GROUP  BY DET.SAP_MATERIAL
        ) F
        ON F.SAP_MATERIAL = M.SAP_MATERIAL
```

Answer (score 1):

Pensar en optimizar código teniendo pocos datos para el escenario, es cuanto menos complicado. Pero puedes probar varios escenarios además del que ya te ha sugerido @Patricio Moracho, utilizando una tabla derivada es seguro mucho más eficiente, que una subconsulta.

Ahora bien, como introduces la etiqueta Sql Server, quizá puedas mejorar la misma utilizando por ejemplo Last_Value.

```
CREATE TABLE MATERIAL
(SAP_MATERIAL VARCHAR(100), 
 CODIGO       INT
);

CREATE TABLE cabecera_Entrada
(fecha_envio DATETIME, 
 numero_guia INT, 
 tipo_guia   INT, 
 id_bodega   INT, 
 bod_salida  INT
);

CREATE TABLE detalle_entrada
(numero_guia  INT, 
 tipo_guia    INT, 
 id_bodega    INT, 
 bod_salida   INT, 
 sap_material VARCHAR(100)
);
GO
INSERT INTO MATERIAL (SAP_MATERIAL,CODIGO)
VALUES
('A',1),
('B',2);
GO
INSERT INTO cabecera_Entrada (fecha_envio, numero_guia, tipo_guia, id_bodega, bod_salida)
VALUES 
('20190101',1,1,1,1),
('20190201',1,1,1,1),
('20190301',1,1,1,1),
('20190401',1,1,1,1),
('20190501',2,2,2,2),
('20190601',2,2,2,2);
GO
INSERT INTO detalle_entrada (numero_guia, tipo_guia, id_bodega, bod_salida, sap_material)
VALUES
(1,1,1,1,'A'),
(2,2,2,2,'B');
GO
```

Es evidente que el escenario no será exactamente lo que tú planteas, porque ni siquiera he definido primary keys para ninguna tabla, pero al objeto de lo que te voy a mostrar puede ser suficiente, ya que eres tú quien tiene que evaluar, y en que condiciones una consulta puede ser más eficaz que otra.

```
SELECT  M.SAP_MATERIAL,
    CODIGO AS CODIGO_PUENTE,
    F.ULTIMO AS FECHA
FROM MATERIAL AS M 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT TOP 1 LAST_VALUE(  
                   FECHA_ENVIO) OVER(ORDER BY FECHA_ENVIO DESC) AS ULTIMO,    DET.sap_material
                   FROM CABECERA_ENTRADA AS CAB
                   INNER JOIN DETALLE_ENTRADA AS DET 
                       ON DET.NUMERO_GUIA = CAB.NUMERO_GUIA 
                       AND DET.TIPO_GUIA = CAB.TIPO_GUIA 
                       AND DET.ID_BODEGA = CAB.ID_BODEGA 
                       AND DET.BOD_SALIDA = CAB.BOD_SALIDA


    ) AS F ON F.sap_material = M.SAP_MATERIAL
```

Otra opción, utilizando el operador Apply

```
SELECT  M.SAP_MATERIAL,
    CODIGO AS CODIGO_PUENTE,
    F.ULTIMO AS FECHA
FROM MATERIAL AS M 
CROSS APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 LAST_VALUE(  
                   FECHA_ENVIO) OVER(ORDER BY FECHA_ENVIO DESC) AS ULTIMO, DET.sap_material
                   FROM CABECERA_ENTRADA AS CAB
                   INNER JOIN DETALLE_ENTRADA AS DET 
                       ON DET.NUMERO_GUIA = CAB.NUMERO_GUIA 
                       AND DET.TIPO_GUIA = CAB.TIPO_GUIA 
                       AND DET.ID_BODEGA = CAB.ID_BODEGA 
                       AND DET.BOD_SALIDA = CAB.BOD_SALIDA


    ) AS F
```

En todas las opciones planteadas, ya que necesitas la última fecha, disponer de un índice por Fecha_Envio sería muchísimo más eficiente.

Comment: Tu solución tambien me hes válida al igual que la de @Patricio Moracho. respecto al esquema no he puesto nada ya que pensaba que no aportaba nada, lo que buscaba era alternativas a las subquerys.